# Can't convert lowercase to uppercase with pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, toupper

So I want to make lowercase letters to uppercase with one condition,     before the lowercase letter there must be space, but the problem is I can't 
check if the next char in the array(using +1) is a space or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void convertToUpper( char *array );

int main()
{   
   char x[] = "i believe i can do it";
   convertToUpper(x);
   printf("%s",x);

   return 0;
}

void convertToUpper( char *array )
{
   while( *array != '\0' )
   {        
       if( *( array + 1 ) != ' ' && *array == ' ' )
       {
           *( ++array) = toupper( *(array) );   
       }
      ++array;
   }
}
```

Comment: `if( *( array + 1 ) != ' ' && *array == ' ' )` logic?

Comment: i would  imagine, that this should have checked that space char is followed by non space char. But it actually does something different, and probably recieves an out of bounds

Comment: Do you mean you would like to Capitalize the words? Should the output be: "I Believe I Can Do It" ?

Comment: well i just found the mistakes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply convert the wrong character, because in your condition, `*array` is space, you should convert the letter after it:

```
while(*array != '\0')
{        
    if( *(array + 1) != ' ' && *array == ' ')
        *(array + 1) = toupper(*(array + 1));
    ++array;
}
```

This simple check won't work for the 1st char, if it should be upper case too, add following before the loop:

```
if (*array != ' ')
    *array = toupper(*array)
```

Comment: yeah,just realized this also

Comment: You have make a performance gain by increasing the array point by two if you do the `toupper`, one otherwise

Comment: @EdHeal yeah, that's right, if converted then advance the pointer by two would be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
void convertToUpper( char *array )
{
   while (  array[0] != 0) && (array[1] != 0) )
   {        
       if( (array[1] != ' ') && (array[0] == ' ' )
           array[1] = toupper( array[1] ); 
       ++array;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way remembers the previous character

```
char previous = ' ';
while(*array != '\0') {        
    if(previous == ' ') {
        *array = toupper(*array);
    }
    previous = *array++;
}
```

just after an answer accepted, but I post anyway.